# SharePoint My site & Delve Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript, office-365, master-page, mysite

I have done Branding through Javacript Injection (Custom Action ) in Office 365 My site. Now office Default my site about me page change to Delve.

In that Delve page (Me.aspx) my javascript injection not working. Javascript not loaded.

Is there a change in master page issue or anything else

Please suggest me the solution. If two different masterpage in my site than how javasctipt injection work? I used PNP githhub demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read [here](http://laneyvb.info/?cat=11), Delve doesn't use any master page.
You cannot make script injection in Delve...

Comment: Thanks for the ans .. You are right. Anyway that i can insert only link or logo inside the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so, for now.